# How to append each variable in array bash Script

Tags: arrays, bash, if-statement, append, element

i want to append the variables values inside each condition into array  as per the sequence i.e here first 60s then 59.8S at last 30.8N.I want to add the elements 
By my code only the last 4 elements are getting appended in array.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq -60 1 30);do
nextint=$((i+1))
sum=$((i+nextint))
mid=`echo "$sum / 2" | bc -l`

sum=`echo $i + $mid | bc`
topmid=`echo "$sum / 2" | bc -l`

sum=`echo $mid + $nextint | bc`
bottommid=`echo "$sum / 2" | bc -l`
k=0.0
#printf "$i%.*f\n$topmid%.*f\n$mid%.*f\n$bottommid%.*f\n"
# "$topmid $mid $bottommid"

#printf "%.*f\n" $i $topmid $mid $botttommid
   n='N'
   s='S'
   array=()
if (( $(echo "$i == $k" | bc -l) )); then
       i=$( printf "%.f\n" "$i")
      topmid=$(printf "%.1f\n" "$topmid")
      mid=$(printf "%.1f\n" "$mid")
     bottommid=$( printf "%.1f\n" "$bottommid")

           topmid=$topmid$n
           mid=$mid$n
           bottommid=$bottommid$n
           echo "$i"
           echo "$topmid"
           echo "$mid"
           echo "$bottommid"

         array+=("$i")
         array+=("$topmid")
         array+=("$mid")
         array+=("$bottommid")
# echo "${array[@]}"
#fi
#done
elif (( $( echo "$i > $k" |bc -l ) ))
        #n='N'
then
      i=$( printf "%.f\n" "$i")
      topmid=$(printf "%.1f\n" "$topmid")
      mid=$(printf "%.1f\n" "$mid")
     bottommid=$( printf "%.1f\n" "$bottommid")
           i=$i$n
           topmid=$topmid$n
           mid=$mid$n
           bottommid=$bottommid$n
           echo "$i"
     #      eco "${array[@]}"
           echo "$topmid"
           echo "$mid"
           echo "$bottommid"
          array+=("$i")  
         array+=("$topmid")
         array+=("$mid")
         array+=("$bottommid")
else
        #s='S'
<<com
      printf "%.f\n" "$i"
      printf "%.1f\n" "$topmid"
      printf "%.1f\n" "$mid"
      printf "%.1f\n" "$bottommid"
com
      i=$( printf "%.f\n" "$i")
      topmid=$(printf "%.1f\n" "$topmid")
      mid=$(printf "%.1f\n" "$mid")
      bottommid=$( printf "%.1f\n" "$bottommid")
           i=$(echo $i$s| sed 's/-//g')
           topmid=$(echo $topmid$s | sed 's/-//g')
           mid=$(echo $mid$s | sed 's/-//g')
           bottommid=$(echo $bottommid$s | sed 's/-//g')
           echo "$i"
           echo "$topmid"
           echo "$mid"
           echo "$bottommid"
          array+=(" $i")
         array+=(" $topmid")
         array+=(" $mid")
         array+=("$bottommid")


fi
done
echo "${array[*]}"
echo "${#array[@]}"
```

output is ---
60S
59.8S
59.5S
59.2S
59S
58.8S
58.5S
58.2S
58S
.....
28.8N
29N
29.2N
29.5N
29.8N
30N
30.2N
30.5N
30.8N
30N 30.2N 30.5N 30.8N
4

I want array to whole variables values as elements in sequence 60N 59.8N ....... 30N 30.2N 30.5N 30.8N

TIA.**
I want array to whole variables values as elements in sequence 60N 59.8N ....... 30N 30.2N 30.5N 30.8N **

Answer (score 0):

Move `array=()` outside of the loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=()
for i in $(seq -60 1 30);do
nextint=$((i+1))
sum=$((i+nextint))
mid=`echo "$sum / 2" | bc -l`

sum=`echo $i + $mid | bc`
topmid=`echo "$sum / 2" | bc -l`

sum=`echo $mid + $nextint | bc`
bottommid=`echo "$sum / 2" | bc -l`
k=0.0
#printf "$i%.*f\n$topmid%.*f\n$mid%.*f\n$bottommid%.*f\n"
# "$topmid $mid $bottommid"

#printf "%.*f\n" $i $topmid $mid $botttommid
   n='N'
   s='S'

if (( $(echo "$i == $k" | bc -l) )); then
       i=$( printf "%.f\n" "$i")
      topmid=$(printf "%.1f\n" "$topmid")
      mid=$(printf "%.1f\n" "$mid")
     bottommid=$( printf "%.1f\n" "$bottommid")

           topmid=$topmid$n
           mid=$mid$n
           bottommid=$bottommid$n
           echo "$i"
           echo "$topmid"
           echo "$mid"
           echo "$bottommid"

         array+=("$i")
         array+=("$topmid")
         array+=("$mid")
         array+=("$bottommid")
# echo "${array[@]}"
#fi
#done
elif (( $( echo "$i > $k" |bc -l ) ))
        #n='N'
then
      i=$( printf "%.f\n" "$i")
      topmid=$(printf "%.1f\n" "$topmid")
      mid=$(printf "%.1f\n" "$mid")
     bottommid=$( printf "%.1f\n" "$bottommid")
           i=$i$n
           topmid=$topmid$n
           mid=$mid$n
           bottommid=$bottommid$n
           echo "$i"
     #      eco "${array[@]}"
           echo "$topmid"
           echo "$mid"
           echo "$bottommid"
          array+=("$i")  
         array+=("$topmid")
         array+=("$mid")
         array+=("$bottommid")
else
        #s='S'
<<com
      printf "%.f\n" "$i"
      printf "%.1f\n" "$topmid"
      printf "%.1f\n" "$mid"
      printf "%.1f\n" "$bottommid"
com
      i=$( printf "%.f\n" "$i")
      topmid=$(printf "%.1f\n" "$topmid")
      mid=$(printf "%.1f\n" "$mid")
      bottommid=$( printf "%.1f\n" "$bottommid")
           i=$(echo $i$s| sed 's/-//g')
           topmid=$(echo $topmid$s | sed 's/-//g')
           mid=$(echo $mid$s | sed 's/-//g')
           bottommid=$(echo $bottommid$s | sed 's/-//g')
           echo "$i"
           echo "$topmid"
           echo "$mid"
           echo "$bottommid"
          array+=(" $i")
         array+=(" $topmid")
         array+=(" $mid")
         array+=("$bottommid")


fi
done
echo "${array[*]}"
echo "${#array[@]}"
```

Effectively, you're emptying it on every bit of the loop, and you set a maximum of 4 values. `set -x` is great for diagnosing these types of issues.

Use `https://www.shellcheck.net/` to check your code. Best practice and all that.